# MSVS 2012, range-based for loop and Boost.Range

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

Consider this Boost.Range and C++11 range-based for loop usage, it doesn't compile with MSVS 2012:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/find.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;

    for(auto i : boost::find(vec, 1))
    {
        std::cout << "lolwut";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
1>...\main.cpp(10): error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'boost::container::container_detail::vector_iterator<Pointer>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Pointer=int *
1>          ]
1>...\main.cpp(10): error C3312: no callable 'end' function found for type 'boost::container::container_detail::vector_iterator<Pointer>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Pointer=int *
1>          ]
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Boost.Range cannot be used inside range-based for loop? Or what do I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `find` returns iterator, not range. You can make another range using `make_iterator_range`

Comment: Oh, looks like my mistake. So range algorithms accepts ranges (but not returns), right?

Comment: For each algorithm you can see what its return type is: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms.html

Comment: Some range algorithms return ranges, others do not. The question _what should `find(range, value)` return?_ has been debated many times. The two most popular answers have been: (a) return a range where the first element is `== value` (or empty if no element is equal), or (b) an iterator referencing the first items that compared equal.

Comment: (Part of) the problem is that the iterator-based `find(begin, end, value)` call implicitly returns _two_ ranges; the first one is all the values that did not match `[begin, return-value)`, and the second one is the range that begins with the matched value `[return-value, end)` - which is option (a) above